# SQL Server Case with Session

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an issue where I'm trying to show a result based on a time frame being either greater than 24 hours, greater than 18 hours or less than 18 hours where a  My query thus far is written as

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HH,DATEADD(SECOND, inc.ORIGINATION_DATE, '19700101'),DATEADD(hour,6,GETDATE())) > 24 then 2 
WHEN DATEDIFF(HH,DATEADD(SECOND, inc.ORIGINATION_DATE, '19700101'),DATEADD(hour,6,GETDATE())) > 18 then 1 
Else 0 End) as DIFFERENCE
   FROM dbo.HELP_DESK as inc
   WHERE inc.LOGIN_ID in "some user"
     and NOT EXISTS (SELECT work.Description from dbo.WORKLOG as work WHERE 
     work.INCIDENT_NUMBER = inc.INCIDENT_NUMBER 
     and work.WORK_LOG_TYPE =  '16000' 
     and work.WORK_LOG_SUBMITTER in "User Group")
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HH,DATEADD(SECOND, chg.ORIGINATION_DATE, '19700101'),DATEADD(hour,6,GETDATE())) > 24 then 2 
WHEN DATEDIFF(HH,DATEADD(SECOND, chg.ORIGINATION_DATE, '19700101'),DATEADD(hour,6,GETDATE())) > 18 then 1 
Else 0 End) as DIFFERENCE
   FROM dbo.INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE as chg
   WHERE chg.ASLOGID in "some user"
     and NOT EXISTS (SELECT work.Description from dbo.WORKLOG as work WHERE 
     work.CHANGE_ID = chg.CHANGE_ID  
     and work.WORK_LOG_TYPE =  '31000' 
     and work.WORK_LOG_SUBMITTER in "User Group")
```

My output in this example is:

```
+------------+
| DIFFERENCE |
+------------+
|          2 |
|          2 |
+------------+
```

I have multiple values >24 so obviously due to the union Im showing two separate values correctly as 2. However, what I want to do is somehow group them so I have a single output of 2, 1 or 0 that I can then output to a PHP session.

some form of count or group by both seem to fail unless I'm incorrectly grouping. There's also probably a better way of doing this but I appear to be taking the long road round.

Appreciate any pointers in taking me forward.

Comment: I may have my answer, change the union all to a union.

Answer (score 0):

A simple change from UNION ALL to UNION returned the single result I was after to output a session value